# Conceptual: public static function vs public function of a class having no constructor and attributes

Tags: class, oop, static, execution-time

This question is only meant to clear the concepts, so please do not emphasis on "why would someone write up a class like that"

I already know that how static functions can be accessed without making an instance of an object (means not modifying state of an object). But lets consider this case of two classes having only two functions in it:

```
class A {
    /* no class attributes */
    /* no constructor */
    public function someFunction(){
    }

    public static function someStaticFunction(){
    }
}
```

```
class B {
    /* no class attributes */
    /* no constructor */
    public function some_function(){
    }

    public function someNonStaticFunction(){
    /* with same implementation as of A::someStaticFunction() */ 
    }
}
```

For class A: there is no constructor and attributes, and all the functions are public. So,

1. Is there any purpose of declaring a function as static for such class?
2. Instead of using class A, if I use class B then I can call the function after making an instance of this class. What would it cost to call the function like this? In terms of execution time and memory (considering no constructor and attributes)
3. Making an instance of a class allocates memory to the object, but do the object consumes memory if it has no attributes at all?
4. Does calling the function as static will automatically flushes out the memory, after the function is completely executed? Or no memory is consumed by the function itself (the only cost is computation and memory of the variables inside)?

Answer (score 1):

A static method is an OO language's hack for not allowing normal functions (I'm looking at you Java!).

A static method is a method on a class, which does not manipulate the state of any of the object instances derived from that class. (That's not 100% accurate, a static method can still manipulate any sort of object, as long as it's passed into it).

In a nutshell, **if your method doesn't have the `this` keyword in it, it's static**. Whether you actually call it static, or initialize a dummy instance for it, doesn't really matter.

Comment: thnx alot.. but the question isn't actually related to java. it's more on OOP.
can you please define if someone has the above scenario of a class then what is better option? to make static or call it via instance? what will be its efficiency? in time and memory..

Comment: or if "java" tag that i have edited is confusing so should i remove the tag? i edited java only because i know that java people are good at OOP :)

Comment: @DanishAhmed: If the question isn't about Java, it shouldn't be tagged Java. PHP and JavaScript people are good at OOP, it doesn't mean you tag them too.

Comment: i m new to this.. i m sorry :) i edited my tags..
by the way thnx :)